# Session message problem in if-else condition

Tags: php, sql

**Intro**

In the table of MySQL server, `crimenews_url` is UNIQUE. I also used INSERT INTO ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE to prevent duplicate input for MySQL server.

So I want to show the session message using an if-else statement to check the condition.

**Notes**

The session message show on the main page but I think that there are some errors in the if-else statement.

**Add.php**

```
     if(isset($_POST['Save']))
     {
         $category = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['category']);
         $url = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['url']);
         $datetime = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['datetime']);
         $lat = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['lat']);
         $lng = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['lng']);
         $conn->query("INSERT INTO crimenews (crimenews_cat, crimenews_url, crimenews_datetime, crimenews_locationLat, crimenews_locationLong) VALUES ('$category', '$url', '$datetime', '$lat', '$lng') ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE crimenews_url = VALUES(crimenews_url)");

         $conn->query("SELECT * FROM crimenews");
         //If there is no duplicated URL inserted into MySQL server
         if(crimenews_url == $url)
         {
           $_SESSION['message'] = "The news has already existed.";
           $_SESSION['msg_type'] = "danger";
         }
         //If there is duplicated URL insert into MySQL server
         else
         {
           $_SESSION['message'] = "The news has added.";
           $_SESSION['msg_type'] = "success";
         }
         header("location: front.php");
     }
```

**front.php** (Session displaying part - The message is shown)

```
    <?php if (isset($_SESSION['message'])): ?>
         <div class="alert alert-<?=$_SESSION['msg_type']?> alert-dismissible fade show" role="alert">
             <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert"><span style='font-size:25px;'>&#215;</span></button>
    <?php
         echo $_SESSION['message'];
         unset($_SESSION['message']);
    ?>
        </div>
    <?php endif ?>
```

**Expected result**

if (the input URL = URL in MYSQL server) -> session message = `The news has already existed.`
else -> session message = `The news has added.`

Comment: I'm not understanding. What is your problem/actual output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to define the `crimenews_url` in order to use it in an **if else** statement.
Update your **Add.php**

```
if(isset($_POST['Save']))
     {
         $category = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['category']);
         $url = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['url']);
         $datetime = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['datetime']);
         $lat = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['lat']);
         $lng = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['lng']);
         $conn->query("INSERT INTO crimenews (crimenews_cat, crimenews_url, crimenews_datetime, crimenews_locationLat, crimenews_locationLong) VALUES ('$category', '$url', '$datetime', '$lat', '$lng') ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE crimenews_url = VALUES(crimenews_url)");

         $result = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM crimenews");

         if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
            // output data of each row
           while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
           $crimenews_url = $row["crimenews_url"];
           }
         }
         //If there is no duplicated URL inserted into MySQL server
         if($crimenews_url == $url)
         {
           $_SESSION['message'] = "The news has already existed.";
           $_SESSION['msg_type'] = "danger";
         }
         //If there is duplicated URL insert into MySQL server
         else
         {
           $_SESSION['message'] = "The news has added.";
           $_SESSION['msg_type'] = "success";
         }
         header("location: front.php");
     }
```